# Excel Freezes With RTD Call

Tags: vb.net, excel, rtd

So, this used to never happen before and now it is doing it every single time.

The RTD server is off now for testing purposes and there is nothing that the Excel really has to do but spit out #N/A. The weird thing is it works fine and fails with the false/wrong progID, yet with a correct one (server still off) it hangs and freezes.

> =RTD("correct.prog",,"TEST")

The above will freeze Excel; it does communicate with the RTD and the RTD turns on and does what it is supposed to, just Excel is freezing

> =RTD("wrong.prog",,"TEST2")

The above does nothing to Excel and Excel does what it is supposed to and outputs #N/A

Answer (score 0):

I bet your overlooking something simple. Here are some idea's:

1. Do you call ShowDialog() without a Parentwindow.
   You can check it if you press Alt+Tab and see if there is a Window in the Back.
2. When you Debug and you press Pause, did the code control stop in the Debugger?

a) If it did then debug your code. It could be a Infinite-Loop.
b) If the debugger did not halt in your code, double check that you have not disabled Excel settings that make it appear in a hung/freeze state:

```
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
xlApp.UserControl = true;
xlApp.EnableEvents = true;
```